# FreeForm and EE 3 missing language file/unable to load the requested language file

Tags: solspace-freeform

3.2.1 fresh install and Freeform 5.01 whenever I try and submit a form it produces the error

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/email_lang.php
```

This is the first site I have tried with EE3 but have built many with EE 2. I am not familiar with the 3.x directory structure so I went searching and there are several directories with a language folder and none of them seem to have the required file. I double checked that things aren't missing from the original install.

The error appears when the form is submitted. The data does find its way into freeform though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Struggling with the same issue.
Any luck?

Comment: I ended up redoing the site in EE2 as I needed to get it launched. Since then EE posted that the issue was with the way they rolled out email module in EE core. They say they have fixed the bug in the latest version. Update to the latest and you should be good.